# Nginx redirect for some url (return 404)

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

How to create a redirect for url returned to 404 (in cms). Use nginx+php-fmp.

Example. There is a category /auto/ with 4 pages:

1. /auto.html,
2. /auto/page-2.html,
3. /auto/page-3.html,
4. /auto/page-4.html

How for the others urls (/auto/page-5.html ... /auto/page-200.html) return 301 to /auto.html?

This code, return 301 for all url (/auto/page-2.html, /auto/page-5.html ...). What is the error?

```
location ~* /(auto)/page-\d+\.html {
  error_page 404 = @page;
}
location @page {
  rewrite /(.*?)/page-\d+\.html http://site.ru/$1.html permanent;
}
error_page 404 =404       /404.html;
location ~* \.php$          {
  include                   fastcgi_def;
}
location /                  {try_files $uri /index.php?$args;}
```

Comment: error_page 404 =404         /404.html;
      location ~* \.php$          {
        include                   fastcgi_def;
        include                   add/cachephp;
        if ($request_uri ~ /(.+)/page-\d+\.html) {
         error_page 404 = @page;
        }
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
      }
      location /                  {try_files $uri /index.php?$args;}
      
      location @page {
        if ($request_uri ~ /(.+)/page-\d+\.html) {return 301 /$1.html;}
        return 410;
      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution

```
error_page 404 =404         /404.html;
  location ~* \.php$          {
    include                   fastcgi_def;
    include                   add/cachephp;
    if ($request_uri ~ /(.+)/page-\d+\.html) {
     error_page 404 = @page;
    }
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  }
  location /                  {try_files $uri /index.php?$args;}

  location @page {
    if ($request_uri ~ /(.+)/page-\d+\.html) {return 301 /$1.html;}
    return 410;
  }
```